# Spark import of the mllib package member

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to import from Spark [CholeskyDecomposition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/CholeskyDecomposition.scala).

I do it in the next way. First of all I have modified my sbt file and add additional dependency:

```
"org.apache.spark"%%"spark-mllib"%"1.3.0"
```

then I do import in my Scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.CholeskyDecomposition
```

When I execute my code (via build.sbt) I have got the next error message:

> object CholeskyDecomposition is not a member of package
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg

When I modify my import statement just to:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg
```

everything is going good and the code is executed without error messages (of course without CholeskyDecomposition object). 
Anyway, I'm pretty sure the object CholeskyDecomposition is a member of linalg package of mllib Spark.
I also just copy the import statement and couldn't do an syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a member of `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg`now, but it wasn't in `spark-mllib` 1.3.

I'm not even sure when it was introduced but I believe that it has been added since `1.6.0-SNAPSHOT` when I read the [commits](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/7bf07faa716bd6a01252c5e888d0956096bde026/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg). (commit hash : 7bf07faa716bd6a01252c5e888d0956096bde026)

Comment: ok, thank you, I will modify my build.sbt file and set to 1.6.0 version

Comment: Now I can do import. but my code fragment doesn't work. I have next code: `CholeskyDecomposition.solve(x, y)`, and error message is `object CholeskyDecomposition in package linalg cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg`

Comment: That's because it's a private object. I've never used to be honest but with a hack, you might be able to use the solver. I can't try to find a fix now because I don't have access to an IDE or a spark cluster to test.